# Including external file 'signalr.min.js' window is not defined

Tags: javascript, selenium, opentest

Versions

- OpenTest --version 1.2.2
- ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87

Including the external javascript files I require will always throw something like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to evaluate JavaScript code at line number 1. The script content was: 
$include(["signalr.min.js", "signalr.tests.js"]);
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to run script file signalr.min.js
...
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
```

I followed the docs at:

- https://getopentest.org/reference/javascript-api.html#includeincludesource
- https://getopentest.org/docs/scripting-support.html#external-script-files

But none of the combinations I tried seems to work, I guess I'm missing something :(

I have the actor.yml configured with the chrome web-driver like this:

```
# Selenium options
selenium:
    # seleniumServerUrl: http://127.0.0.1:9515
    desiredCapabilities:
        browserName: chrome
        chromeOptions:
            args: [ --start-maximized ]
    chromeDriverExePath: C:/Webdrivers/chromedriver.exe
    chromeDriverExeArgs: [--start-maximized, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-popup-blocking, --disable-extensions-file-access-check, "--test-name", "--disable-extensions", "--disable-notifications", "--disable-web-security", "--disable-prompt-on-repost", "--browser-test", "--dom-automation", "--enable-caret-browsing", "--expose-internals-for-testing", "--force-login-manager-in-tests" ]
```

An example of the test in question:

```
description: My Test
actors:
  - actor: ACTOR1
    segments:
      - segment: 1
        actions:
          - description: include external SignalR script files
            script: |
                $include(["signalr.min.js", "signalr.tests.js"]);

          - description: Initialize SignalR Connection
            action: org.getopentest.selenium.ExecuteScript
            args:
              scriptArgs: $data("config").webChatUrl + $data("config").apiV1SignalRChathub
              script: |
                var hubUrl = arguments[0];
                SignalRConnectionTest(hubUrl);
```

The signalr.min.js can be found at: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/3.1.7/signalr.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of trail and error I managed to get something working. I never got the script-includes working in OpenTest. I figure that is because there are issues when the browser is not opened (yet), and so the `window` will just be undefined. So basically you can only include scripts that do not use the DOM...

What I did, was create a "local" html page that runs some of the javascript, and call that page from the OpenTest yml with some checks. here is an example of what I did:

```
description: My Test
actors:
  - actor: ACTOR1
    segments:
      - segment: 1
        actions:
          - description: Initialize Browser
            action: org.getopentest.selenium.NavigateTo
            args:
              url: $data("config").someExternalUrlIsAlive
              
          - description: Get Test Page File-Path
            script: |
              var File = Java.type("java.io.File");
              var URLEncoder = Java.type("java.net.URLEncoder");
              var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");

              var testPage = new File("..\\test-repo\\scripts\\testpage.html");
              var testPageUrl = testPage.getAbsolutePath();

              var argument = $data("config").someProperty;
              var argumentUrlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(argument, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());

              $sharedData.testpage = testPageUrl + "?arg=" + argumentUrlEncoded;
              $log("The test-page path is " + $sharedData.testpage);

          - description: Navigate to Test Page
            action: org.getopentest.selenium.NavigateTo
            args:
              url: $sharedData.testpage

          - description: Start Test
            action: org.getopentest.selenium.Click
            args:
              locator: { id: btnTest }

          - description: Give the test some time to complete
            script: |
              var Thread = Java.type("java.lang.Thread");
              Thread.sleep(3000); // sleep 3 seconds.

          - description: Read Test Page Result
            action: org.getopentest.selenium.GetElements
            args:
              locator: { id: txtResult }
              $localData:
                resultElements: $output.elements

          - description: Validate the Test Page Results
            script: |
              var txtResult = $localData.resultElements[0];
              var testResult = txtResult.getAttribute("value")

              if (testResult !== "200") {
                $fail(
                  $format(
                    "We expected a valid connection result, but we got: {0}",
                    testResult
                  )
                );
              }
```